# How to quickly design and simulate crank based mechanisms?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, linkage

I'm doing a project on Theo Jansen's Mechanism, where I have to modify the mechanism. What is the most efficient way to design these mechanisms? Is there any good software where I can just draw the links and input crank and test out the mechanism? I have used GeoGebra, but it doesn't simulate the mechanism physically, and while using Creo I found that the pin joints often get stuck - like they suddenly fold up and do not move. Also, creating the links one by one takes quite a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D CAD software has a hard time with lots of pin connections, because without a range limitation the solution is indeterminate. I have not used Creo, but if you can limit the range of motion with interference or other, the model may work.

[Working Model 2D](http://www.design-simulation.com/wm2d/) is nice for designing mechanisms. I used it as a student; not sure how much it costs commercially.

Comment: Looks good. But maybe something with a free student license? I live in India, and due to currency conversion rates, 25 dollars is worth a lot of money here.

Comment: You should be able to get Creo to work :-) The following link talks about how to add rotational constraints to pins. https://community.ptc.com/t5/Additional-Creo-Questions/Applying-Rotational-Constraints/td-p/235837

Comment: Thanks. Although it still doesn't work in Creo for me, I got it to work on Solidworks :)